# How to remove autoscroll, when I typing text in TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I tried to remove and request focus when only if I dont typing text - all don't work. How can I fix that?

TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText inserted in recyclerview

[image]

Comment: Is that a recyclerview with all the edittexts ?

Comment: Yes, all items of recyclerview is TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

Comment: You must add more detail. Etc: code, log

Comment: Cant show code, coz project has nda. So I think need handle `canScrollVertically` and combine that with focus of ui component. After tests I will report results

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest for example to do something like this:

```
...
// at the top of the class
boolean canScrowVertically = true;
...
...
// init recycler
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
... 
...
// Init linerLayout and override canScrollVertically method
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return canScrowVertically;
    }
};
...
...
// Set the manager
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
...
```

Then you can manipulate `canScrowVertically` to disable/enable the scrow.